# Smartsheet SDK compatible on Amazon AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, smartsheet-api-2.0

Does anyone know if Smartsheet SDK is compatible with Amazon's AWS Lambda?  I have a ticket in for Smartsheet but haven't heard from them yet so I thought I would give it a try here.

I'm getting a time-out when running this command on AWS "**sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(SHEET_ID)**".

**AWS Lambda error message:**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-02-19T18:33:11.477Z cbad2464-4195-4a54-ac72-ea53c2786b75 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"
}
```

Thanks!

**Python (version 3.8) Code:**

```
  # Name of the Smartsheet being updated
  SHEET_ID = "CENIC Circuit Master Sheet Current"

  smartsheet = Smartsheet(TOKEN)
#  print("DeBug 3 sheet = ", smartsheet) 
  # This is the problem below.
  **sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(SHEET_ID)**
  # Make sure we don't miss any errors
  smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)
```

Runs fine on Ubuntu latest version.

Comment: That's Amazon AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an invalid statement. `Sheets` (capital 'S') requires a numeric sheet ID, not the name of a sheet. [See the documentation](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet) for a details. This is why an error is occurring.

```
sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(4583173393803140)
```

### Why the time out error?

You are enabling `errors_as_exceptions` after you've already made the call. So you aren't getting useful information from the error. Revise your code to something like this:

```
smartsheet.errors_as_exceptions(True)

SHEET_ID = 4583173393803140  # You must retrieve the Sheet ID first, names are not allowed
try:
    sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_ID)
    print(sheet)
except Exception as e: 
    print(e.message)
```

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try.  Thank you!

Comment: That took care of the syntax.  Still got the time-out error at 50 seconds.  I don't want to go over that since billing is being closely watched.  And so, I made a smaller file on Smartsheet and downloaded that within 20 seconds.  Its a stub Smartsheet (a sub-portion of the original Smartsheet) with the columns that I actually use.